# Greedy algorithm visualization

Tags: python, algorithm, queue, visualization, greedy

I have a problem which goes as follows.
There are `n` items. Each item `i` takes `m_i` time to manufacture and `t_i` time to test. Obviously, an item must be manufactured before being tested. At any point of time, manufacturing queue and testing queue can have only one item in each of them. Now, the objective is to schedule the items to minimize the total production time.

I have written the code for this:

```py
# data is a list of lists which will be in the form of [[id, m_i, t_i]]
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])  # Sort by manufacturing time
print(f"Items will be produced in the order: {', '.join(str(x[0]) for x in data)}")
idle = 0
last =  0
# Idle time is the total time when the testing unit will have no work
schedule = 0
for item in data:
    if last and last <= item[1]:
        idle = item[1] - last + 1
    schedule += item[2]
    last = schedule + idle
print(f"The total production time is {schedule+idle}")
```

Now, for the following input,

```
1 / 5 / 7
2 / 1 / 2
3 / 8 / 2
4 / 5 / 4
5 / 3 / 7
6 / 4 / 4
```

I want to visualize it this way

[image]

As you can see above, an item is moved to testing queue as soon as it is manufactured and the next item is pulled into the manufacturing queue. If the manufacturing queue still has time left, the testing queue will be idle as there are no drones to be tested. Now, I want to visualize the above code this way.

How to achieve this? I am stuck with this. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Do you want to update the table by inserting new row every time either of manufacturing/testing is finished? Or do you just want the finished table with your algorithm? i.e. do you want an offline or online algorithm to produce the table?

Comment: @Minohcity Either of them is fine. Given an input like the one shown, I just want a table with filled that way. Both of them are good enough though I have a preference to show every row dynamically and the complete table at the end